# Using jeditable on datatables with tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, datatables, jeditable

I'm new when it comes to datatables and jeditable. Right now I'm trying do use jeditable on my datatables but it wont work all the way.
My problem: When i switch tab in my datatable, the jeditable event doesnt follow to the new tab so I can't edit any cell. The first tab is the only one where I can edit cells.

Are there any easy solution for my problem, or are there any other thread about this that I have missed?

```
$("#tabs").tabs( {
    "show": function(event, ui) {
        var oTable = $('div.dataTables_scrollBody>table.display', ui.panel).dataTable();
        if ( oTable.length > 0 ) {
            oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
        }
    }
});

// Sets datatable for main table in offerts(admin).
var oTable = $('.display.offerts').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bStateSave": true,
    "aoColumns": [
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        { "bSortable": false }
    ],
    "oLanguage": {
        "sProcessing": "Processing...",
        "sLengthMenu": "Visa _MENU_ rader",
        "sZeroRecords": "Inga matchande rader funna",
        "sEmptyTable": "Ingen data tillgänglig i tabellen",
        "sLoadingRecords": "Laddar...",
        "sInfo": "Visar _START_ till _END_ av _TOTAL_ rader",
        "sInfoEmpty": "Visar 0 till 0 av 0 rader",
        "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrerat från _MAX_ rader)",
        "sInfoPostFix": "",
        "sSearch": "Sök i alla kolumner:"
    }
});

  /* Apply the jEditable handlers to the table */
    $('td.contacted, td.complete, td.sold', oTable.fnGetNodes()).editable( '../index.php/offerts/update_offert_status', {
        data    : "{'Ja':'Ja','Nej':'Nej'}",
        type    : 'select',
        submit  : 'OK',
        "callback": function( sValue, y ) {
            var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
            oTable.fnUpdate( sValue, aPos[0], aPos[1] );
        },
        "submitdata": function ( value, settings ) {
            return {
                "row_id": this.parentNode.getAttribute('id'),
                "column": oTable.fnGetPosition( this )[2]
            };
        },
        "height": "14px"
    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post your code on jsfiddle.net so that we can help?In any caso also post your full code in the question.

Comment: Thanks and sry that I forgot to add code.

Comment: what about your HTML code? Are you loading the tab via AJAX?

Comment: No. I'm not using ajax but I have tried ajax and it didnt work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think (but i'm guessing since there is no html code) that your problem is that you are initializing more than one datatable here:

```
  var oTable = $('.display.offerts').dataTable
```

And than when you get the nodes from the object you get the nodes of one table only.

```
  $('td.contacted, td.complete, td.sold', oTable.fnGetNodes())
```

If you have more than one table you should use ids and not classes so that you can have different objects on which you can work

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nicola! I thought that I could set settings using a common class but I had to call every table separate using their id.